# How to check if new line is empty in richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I am checking if a line in richtextbox is empty. If not, it will go at the next line.
The code I am using is:

```
Dim text as string="hello"
Dim lines = RichTextBox1.Lines
Dim upperBound = lines.GetUpperBound(0)

If lines(upperBound).Trim() = String.Empty Then
   lines(upperBound) = text
   RichTextBox1.Lines = lines
Else
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & text)
End If
```

Which is working perfectly. But just now I discovered that if Richtextbox1 is completely empty, this code will not add text to it. Is there any way to fix this little bug? Thanks

Comment: This is a great code I took from @jmcilhinney, So in case you see this, your help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this does what you want:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim text As String = "hello"

    If RichTextBox1.Text.Trim = "" Then
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(titolo)
    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Lines(RichTextBox1.Lines.GetUpperBound(0)).Length = 0 Then
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(titolo)
    ElseIf RichTextBox1.Lines(RichTextBox1.Lines.GetUpperBound(0)).Trim = "" Then
        Dim lines = RichTextBox1.Lines
        lines(lines.GetUpperBound(0)) = titolo
        RichTextBox1.Lines = lines
    Else
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim text as string="hello"
Dim lines = RichTextBox1.Lines
Dim empty = {""}

If lines.Length = 0 Then lines = empty
    
Dim upperBound = lines.GetUpperBound(0)

If lines(upperBound).Trim() = String.Empty Then
    lines(upperBound) = titolo
    RichTextBox1.Lines = lines
Else
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & text)
End If
```

Comment: Hi, Using Strict option on, It returns an error on ReDim(lines, 1) : Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this very efficient system.

This is called LinQ for array, You can query an array for a empty line,
if the count is greater than 0 then exit(or give an error)

```
Dim text As String = "hello"
Dim lines = RichTextBox1.Lines
        Dim qry = From n In lines
                  Where n = ""
                  Select n
        If qry.Count > 0 Then
        'you can give some error here
        End If
```

Comment: This is not what I asked for.